# Input string was not in a correct format while adding string to integer

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a code like this :

```
Dim mincatval As String
     Dim strarr() As String = dr1(0).ToString().Split(New Char() {"-"c})
                                Dim i As String
                          i = (Integer.Parse(strarr(0)) + 1)
                                mincatval = i
```

my dr(1) value is L1 i want to add 1,so i want the out put  **L2**,but i am getting error like this :**Input string was not in a correct format.**

Comment: It seems that you think that "L1"  is a number.

Comment: sir,in this case how i can add?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that strarr(0) is the `word`  "L1" and you want it to become "L2" then you need to isolate the numeric part from the text part and then rebuild the string taking the first part of strarr and the incremented value

```
 Dim mincatval As String
 Dim strarr() As String = dr1(0).ToString().Split(New Char() {"-"c})
 Dim i As String
 Dim itShouldBeAnumber = strarr(0).Substring(1)
 if Int32.TryParse(itShouldBeAnumber, i) Then
     mincatval = strarr(0).Substring(0,1) & (i + 1)
 else
     MessageBox.Show("Not a valid number from position 1 of " & strarr(0))
 End if
```

Of course this solution assumes that your string is Always composed of an initial letter followed by a numeric value that could be interpreted as an integer